# Integrating Git Source Control with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

My Visual Studio does not shows git source control provider in status bar.

[I want to know that how this source control shows here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6dz2.png)

Comment: What's the VS version do you use?

Comment: Try `Ctrl + Shift + G`